Beam structures in nested triplets
I'm trying to create a beat of nested tuplets to look like this:

My attempt to reproduce that looks like this:
\version "2.24.3"                                                               
{                                                                  
  r4                                                                            
  \once \override TupletBracket.bracket-visibility = ##t 
  \tuplet 3/2 {                                                                 
    \tuplet 3/2 8 {                                                             
      ais'16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16                                               
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
  8 r r4                                                                       
} 


I'd like the 16th beam to break at every set of three.  I've been trying to set baseMoment/Structure inside of the inner tuplet, out of the inner tuplet, but inside of the outer tuplet, and outside of the outer tuplet, but I can't get it to have any effect.
\set Timing.baseMoment #(ly:make-moment 1/8)
\set Timing.beatStructure 3,3,3


I observe, that you are fine with replacing the ancient quarter rest symbol (nice example, by the way) by a modern one, but want to keep the nested triplet notation. Why not simply use a 9/4 tuplet instead of a partial authenticity approach?

With 2.24 you’d need to do something like this:
\version "2.24"                                                               
{
  \set subdivideBeams = ##t
  r4                                                                            
  \once \override TupletBracket.bracket-visibility = ##t 
  \tuplet 3/2 {
    \set baseMoment = #(ly:make-moment 1/12)
    \set beatStructure = 2,2,2,2,2,2
    \tuplet 3/2 8 {                                                             
      ais'16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16                                               
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
  8 r r4                                                                       
}

Note that with 2.25 this functionality will change, and it suffice to do
\set subdivideBeams = ##t
\set minimumBeamSubdivisionInterval = \musicLength 8

